# Unlearning a single example with Vowpal Wabbit

Tags: machine-learning, vowpalwabbit

Vowpal Wabbit is a tool for online learning. Data points arrive in a stream and the model is updated accordingly to fit the label. I have a question about whether it is possible to unlearn a single data point? Imagine a single data point was consumed and I want to "unlearn" it immediately for some reason. Is it possible in principle with online learning algorithm like Logistic Regression in Vowpal Wabbit?

Answer (score 2):

Such functionality isn't implemented in VW. You can try to workaround this with `-f --save_resume` and `-i` flags to store\restore model state at some point of time but it will be inefficient.

There could be some adjustments made in c++ code to achieve such functionality, but they're highly dependent on training algorithm you use, criteria that makes example unwanted and when this criteria could be applied. For example I played once with GD algo making it ignore while learning (after some time) some examples based on how sure current model in their classification. In other words: don't learn from examples you're unsure in. Thus I could decide if example is unwanted at the same point algorithm receives it and it was easy to implement.

If you're training binary classifier and able to decide that example don't worth to be trained from faster then some meta parameters (like `--decay_learning_rate`) change situation significantly then you can try to feed your model same example with opposite label. That might approximate real "unlearning" well enough and might not. But definitely won't be equal to real "unlearning". Still I would try it before messing with VW sourcecode.

Comment: Good answer. Actually the first suggestion is doable in my current framework. The statistical models are versioned, it is ok to roll back to a previous version by merely loading the previous version.

Comment: It is also a very good suggestion to use only data examples for training which are clean and well understood. This is a lesson I learned when training multiple custom NER models.